# Modify Url's in Sitecore SXA sitemap

Tags: sxa

Our application is on Sitecore 9.0.2 with SXA 1.8.1

we have written custom link provider and Item resolver to omit bucket folders in Url's in our application and is working as expected , we also want the Url's to omit bucket folders on sitemap.xml

I understand that we can override the `SitemapGenerator` to do this but unable to find documentation on which method to override

any help on this ? what is the best way to achieve this functionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to override any processor. The sitemap is generated using `SitemapGenerator` service. Take a look at `GenerateSitemap()` method - this is an entry point (take a look also at `BuildSitemap()` and `GetFullLink()` protected methods).

I would implement my own sitemap generator which will inherit from SXA `SitemapGenerator` service and override just what I need.

As the last step, you need to replace SXA service with your own. You can do it in two ways:

- config patch
- [replace service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590769/replace-service-registration-in-asp-net-core-built-in-di-container) in DI container using code